# Twitter API get more than first 100 retweets

Tags: twitter

given a tweet, I need to obtain the first 100 users who have retweeted my tweet. I.e: If my tweet has 600 re-tweets, I need the user id's of the first 100 people to have done so. NOT the latest 100. There is an API call to find the latest 100 people but is there a way to reverse this and get the first 100? OR is there a way to bypass the 100 user limit and select all the users?

Answer (score 1):

According to Twitter's dev docs, [statuses/retweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3aid) does what you want – "Returns up to 100 of the **first** retweets of a given tweet."